# Rails - Paperclip - How to Check the Image Dimensions before saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I have a Rails 3 app with paperclip.
I want to prevent images with a width/height of LTE 50x50 from being saved by paperclip.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yep! Here's a custom validation I wrote for my app, it should work verbatim in yours, just set the pixels to whatever you want.

```
def file_dimensions
  dimensions = Paperclip::Geometry.from_file(file.queued_for_write[:original].path)
  self.width = dimensions.width
  self.height = dimensions.height
  if dimensions.width < 50 && dimensions.height < 50
    errors.add(:file,'Width or height must be at least 50px')
  end
end
```

One thing to note, I used `self.width=` and `self.height=` in order to save the dimensions to the database, you can leave those out if you don't care to store the image dimensions.

Checking width AND height means that only one has to be greater than 50px. If you want to make sure BOTH are more than 50 you, ironically, need to check width OR height. It seems weird to me that one or the other means an AND check, and both means OR, but in this case that's true.

The only other *gotcha* is, you need to run this validation LAST: if there are already other errors on the model it will raise an exception. To be honest it's been a while so I don't remember what the error messages were, but in your validation macro use this:

```
validate :file_dimensions, :unless => "errors.any?"
```

That should take care of it!

Comment: I get: undefined method `to_file' for <Rake::FileTask  => []>:Rake::FileTask

Comment: Doh! because my attribute is "image" not "file"

Comment: As an update, `to_file` was deprecated and removed. The correct way now is to use `file.queued_for_write[:original]`. https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/812

Comment: Thanks @CalvinL, do you mind taking a look and confirming I changed the answer correctly? I don't use Paperclip anymore so I haven't faced this issue.

Comment: Actually, you need `Paperclip::Geometry.from_file(file.queued_for_write[:original].path)`. Thanks for updating the answer!

Comment: How do you handle when someone is in "edit" and not "new". How do you check the file_dimensions only when they're making a new record?

Comment: I've one question at my end it is not showing error message even if working properly and not uploading image which is not according to required dimensions?

Comment: @VuNguyen `validate :file_dimensions, unless: "errors.any?", on: :create` should do it

Comment: @Andrew I know it's a long time since this question was answered but wouldn't it be better to only validate the file dimensions if there is actually a file given? `validate :file_dimensions, if: 'image.file?'`

Comment: @Andrew I edited the answer which is based on my previous comment. Instead of adding the if statement to the validate method it is better to check if a new file is even queued before validating the dimensions.

Comment: @Andrew : Is that possible to retrieved image dimensions by custom processor?? I want to dispatch not through model but custom processor. Any idea? How can I achieve it?

Comment: @GaganGami, I'm not familiar with using PaperClip outside of a model. Since that doesn't sound like what's covered in this question, you should type up a full example of your situation and ask it as a new question, you're much more likely to get help that way.