# Conditionally generate style of Paperclip attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I am working on an advanced usage of Paperclip.

I have file uploading (images or video) functionality in my project using Paperclip. And I want to generate resized samples for large (for example larger than 1000x1000px) attached files.
I tried this:

```
has_attached_file :upload, styles: { sample: '1000x1000>', preview: ['150x150', :jpg] },
      convert_options: { sample: '-quality 90', preview: '-quality 85 -strip' }
```

But this code **always** generates samples, even for smaller files. Is there any way to check attached file dimensions before sample generating?

Comment: to clarify - if you have a small image it is generating `sample` (but it's left at its original dimensions) and you aren't interested in it at all? you aren't interested in attaching the file to the model through `has_attached_file` ?

Comment: @David yes, I'm not interested in `sample`s for small images, i prefer to use `original` file instead. But for large files I prefer use `sample`s at first and let user to chose between sample and original in view.
And I'm interested in `has_attached_file` file attachment, validation, `preview` generation etc.

Comment: I see ... I'm still unsure on how you propose to attach smaller files to your model but the following question/answer can certainly help you in carrying out pre-processsing of any image queued for paperclip - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454561/rails-paperclip-how-to-check-the-image-dimensions-before-saving

Comment: @David nonono, I still need small images. I want to generate `sample` **only for large images**, and **always** keep `original` and `preview`.

Comment: ok fully understood now ... let me play around with it.

Answer (score 2):

Ok this took longer, than I would have liked, to figure out due to some issue with lambdas and Paperclip which I managed to work around:

You need to use lambda's to decide on which styles to apply dynamically based upon the image size - the image size itself can be determined from the image that is queued for processing.

```
  has_attached_file :image,
                    styles: lambda { |attachment| attachment.instance.decide_styles }

  def decide_styles
    unless @styles
      @styles = {}
      @styles[:preview] = { preview: {
              geometry: "150x150",
              format: :jpg,
              convert_options: "-quality 85 -strip" }}

      dimensions = Paperclip::Geometry.from_file(image.queued_for_write[:original].path)
      if dimensions.width > 1000 or dimensions.height > 1000
        @styles[:sample] = { sample: {
                geometry: "1000x1000>",
                convert_options: "-quality 90" }}
      end
    end

    @styles
  end
```

You need to be aware of a few gotchas though when using lambdas with Paperclip...

1. It seems that you need to specify not only the style but any conversion options etc along with the style. It is not recommended to specify the convert options in a separate lambda.
2. In my case using lambdas with Paperclip just wouldn't work as they should and it appears a few others have had this issue too - the `decide_styles` method was being invoked about 7 times and on the last time it was throwing an exception when trying to determine the dimensions - this is why I'm assigning to `@styles` and testing if that has already been defined (It's not pretty but it works!).

Comment: replace that with `upload.queued_for_write` in your case ... if that works I shall modify the answer accordingly.

Comment: Nah, I mean it returns null for my `has_attached_file` symbol name too.

Comment: again i think in your case that should `be has_attached_file :upload` in your case as that reflects the state of your db.

Comment: can you post your stack trace

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161376/discussion-between-yukarin-and-david).